# Subdomain for windows azure cloud

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

Is it possible to create a subdomain for webroles?

for example i would like to create two webroles and have one point to xxx.mywebsite.com and another point to yyy.mywebsite.com

I couldn't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that's easy. Login to your domain registrar first and go to your DNS/Domain manager page. Add two CNAME entries for each of your webrole.

For example, add a CNAME, xxx and point it to webrole1.cloudapp.net and similarly add yyy and point it to webrole2.cloudapp.net

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you create the subdomin on your DNS server (or wherever your domain is registered) and you point the subdomain to the azure DNS name.